# Recursive list generator function in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I have setup a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/r69ex6k3/1/).

The following code generates an html list from an object

```
function generateList(data, $e) {
    // create an inner item
    function createInner(obj) {
        var li = $('<li>');
        li.text(obj.text);
        if (obj.children != undefined && obj.children.length > 0) {
            innerList = $('<ul>');
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
                var child = obj.children[i];
                innerList.append(createInner(child));
            };
            li.append(innerList);
        }

        return li;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $e.append(createInner(data[i]));
    }
}
```

The following dataset has been used as an example -

```
[
    {
        "text": "item1"
    },
    {
        "text": "item2",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "subItem",
            },
            {
                "text": "another subItem",
            },
            {
                "text": "last subItem",
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "text": "item3",
        "children": [
            {
                "text": "Hello",
            },
            {
                "text": "Inner List",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": "innerItem1",
                    },
                    {
                        "text": "innerItem2",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "text": "Bye",
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

The list item which has item3 written should have an inner list containing two more children, but it is not happening. The item labelled `Inner List` is not shown in the html output. Neither is the item labelled `Hello`. `item3` contains only `innerItem1`, `innerItem2` and `Bye`.

How can I overcome this ?

Comment: Please write the relevant code **in** the question.

Comment: added it in the question

Comment: Your recursive function should take two parameters. The data node to add *and* the parent element to add the result to. They will then work in parallel to any depth.

Comment: it would be great if you could update the fiddle as an example

Comment: Done below. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than try append results returned recursively, your recursive function could take two parameters. The data node to add *and* the parent element to add the result to. They will then work in parallel to any depth:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/r69ex6k3/3/

```
function generateList(data, $e) {
    // create an inner item
    function createInner(obj, $target) {
        var li = $('<li>').appendTo($target);
        li.text(obj.text);
        if (obj.children != undefined && obj.children.length > 0) {
            var innerList = $('<ul>').appendTo(li);
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
                var child = obj.children[i];
                createInner(child, innerList);
            };
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        createInner(data[i], $e);
    }
}
```

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="sample">
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2
        <ul>
            <li>subItem</li>
            <li>another subItem</li>
            <li>last subItem</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item3
        <ul>
            <li>Hello</li>
            <li>Inner List
                <ul>
                    <li>innerItem1</li>
                    <li>innerItem2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Bye</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a variable problem where **innerList** was a global variable. Always define your variables at the beginning of the scope. (http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#variable%20declarations)

Here's the answer: **JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/r69ex6k3/5/

Just needed to clean up the function a little (**createInner**)

```
function createInner(obj) {
        var li = $('<li>'),
            innerList,
            child;
        li.text(obj.text);
        if (obj.children && obj.children.length) {
            innerList = $('<ul>');
            for (var i = 0; i < obj.children.length; i++) {
                child = obj.children[i];
                innerList.append(createInner(child));
            };
            li.append(innerList);
        }

        return li;
    }
```